# How to Update View and View Model without using INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

When we have a twoway binding involved between View and View-Model, we implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface which has the following event:

```
// Summary:
//     Occurs when a property value changes.
event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

But can I do the same without implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: "Do the same" can be interpreted in a few different ways. If you are asking "Can I add an event handler called PropertyChanged", then yes, you can!

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you can't use, or don't like to use INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @Clemens i had this problem aswell. Think of a third party lib, where you want to show objects directly in WPF. Of course usually you would treat these objects as models, and create a viewmodel. But this is pretty difficult when you use something like a PropertyGrid. I had this problem with a Physic engine and a property grid.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` (INPC) (or don't have the source to what you want to bind to) then you should wrap whatever it is you want to bind to in your View Model and the View Model would implement INPC for the binding and have to to get/set data to, presumably, that other class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` explicitly, you could use a code-weaving tool like PostSharp. Then, implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` becomes as simple as

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class Shape
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

You can find more details here: http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/notifypropertychanged# .

Answer (score 1):

You can of course. You simply loose the easy way to update the view when the viewmodel is changed. Now there are ways to overcome that.

1. Reapply the `DataContext`, that way all bindings gets evaluated
   again, but this is very expensive.
2. In the ui, get the binding of the desired property and call
      [UpdateTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatetarget.aspx).

But obviously these are all very strange workarounds. Its also worth mentioning, that binding to an object that doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged is usually slower.

Answer (score 0):

i would say no. you have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in any way, otherwise binding with twoway would not work.